# How can i resize my canvas to fit the browser window?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Hello :) i am currently trying to resize my canvas whenever someone resizes their browser window. Here is my code so far:

html:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js">
 </script>
<script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js">
 </script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="blob.js">
 </script>
 <title>USGame</title>
 <style>
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0;
        overflow: hidden; /*  Disable scrollbars */
        display: block;  /* No floating content on sides */
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js file:

```
  var blob;

 var blobs = [];
 var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(1500, 600);
blob = new Blob(0, 0, 64);
for (var i = 0; i <100; i++) {
var x = random(-width,width);
var y = random(-height,height);
 blobs[i] = new Blob(x, y, 8);
  }
}

function draw() {
 background(3, 3, 40);

 translate(width/2, height/2);
 var newzoom = 64 / blob.r;
 zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
 scale(zoom);
 translate(-blob.pos.x, -blob.pos.y);

 for (var i = blobs.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
 blobs[i].show();
  if (blob.eats(blobs[i])) {
  blobs.splice(i, 1);
  }
 }


 blob.show();
 blob.update();

 }
```

where it says:
        `createCanvas(1500, 600);`

i am setting the **fixed** width and height, when i really want these to adjust to fit someone's browser window. Please explain how i can do this! Thank you!

Comment: use window.onresize function and update the canvas width by using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi :) As it seems from your question, you are using p5.js library, which has a built-in function *(event)* called **[`windowResized()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized)**, that you could use. This function fires on every resize of the browser window.

Once its fired, you can  use another built-in function called **[`resizeCanvas()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/resizeCanvas)**, to resize the canvas size, so that it matches the browser window's width and height.

Here is a quick [example](https://output.jsbin.com/gosogegeju), showing how you could use these functions ...

```js
function setup() {
   createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
   background('#222');
   ellipse(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 100, 100);
   fill('#07C');
   noStroke();
}

function windowResized() {
   resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```css
body{margin:0;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, now is there a way to make the canvas zoom in when i make the page smaller? In my game, you are not supposed to see more of the canvas when making the page bigger, its supposed to be zoomed out. Thanks!

Comment: um.. maybe, but that's a different question. you should rather ask a new question with additional details to get a proper solution for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it.

```js
(function() {
    // get the precentage of height and width  of the cavas based on the height and width of the window
    getPercentageOfWindow = function() {
        var viewportSize = getViewportSize();
        var canvasSize = getCanvastSize();
        return {
            x: canvasSize.width / (viewportSize.width - 10),
            y: canvasSize.height / (viewportSize.height - 10)
        };
    };
    //get the context of the canvas 
    getCanvasContext = function() {
        return $("#myCanvas")[0].getContext('2d');
    };
    // get viewport size
    getViewportSize = function() {
        return {
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth
        };
    };
    // get canvas size
    getCanvastSize = function() {
        var ctx = getCanvasContext();
        return {
            height: ctx.canvas.height,
            width: ctx.canvas.width
        };
    };
    // update canvas size
    updateSizes = function() {
        var viewportSize = getViewportSize();
        var ctx = getCanvasContext();
        ctx.canvas.height = viewportSize.height * percentage.y;
        ctx.canvas.width = viewportSize.width * percentage.x;
    };
    var percentage = getPercentageOfWindow();
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        updateSizes();
    });
}());
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" >
```

And here is the workable [link](http://jsfiddle.net/h6c3rxxf/9/).

Comment: That is a lot of code, Can do the same with (and no need for jQuery) `(function() {
    const can = myCanvas;
    const scale = {
        x: can.width / (innerWidth - 10),
        y: can.height / (innerHeight - 10)
    };
    addEventListener('resize',() => {
        can.width = innerWidth * scale.x;
        can.height = innerHeight * scale.y;
    });
}());`

Answer (score 0):

You just need a window resize handler.

```
function setup() {
  var canvas = createCanvas(1500, 600);
  window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.height = window.outerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.outerWidth;
  }
}
```

Just make sure that createCanvas is returning a reference to your canvas. If you can't find a reference for the element in your code, you can also just search for it in the DOM.

```
window.onresize = function() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.height = window.outerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.outerWidth;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately,  this has no effect on the canvas, it stays at the fixed width and height, and does not change when moving the window. Any idea why?

Comment: is your `createCanvas` function returning a reference to the canvas element?

Comment: i'm new to javascript, could you explain what that means? i dont know if this is helpful but createCanvas is only written there in the whole entire code.

Comment: Somewhere there should be a piece of code like `function createCanvas()`. At the end of it, it should say `return canvas` or something like that.

Comment: nope dont see, if its okay with you, ill message u tomorrow because i have to go right now. thx